# isomorphic finitely generated group

Tags: group-theory

let $H$ be a subgroup of homeomorphisms of the line generated by $f$ and $h$ and let $G$ be also a subgroup of homeomorphisms of the line generated by $f$ and $g$ such that $g$ and $h$ are conjugated by an increasing homeomorphism $r$.

My question is: How do I show that $H$ and $G$ are isomorphic?

Comment: What are $f$ and $h$?

Comment: two homeomorphisms of the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the operation over your groups are composition. $G$ and $H$ need not be isomorphic: Consider $f(x)=2x$, $g(x) = 3x$ and $h(x) = 3x+2$. $g$ and $h$ are conjugate under the map $t(x) = x+1$. You can see that $h=t^{-1}\circ g\circ t$.

On the one hand the group generated by $f$ and $g$ is abelian; in fact you can embed this group into $(\Bbb{R}^\times, \cdot)$. On the other hand, however, the group generated by $f$ and $h$ is *nonabelian* since $g\circ h\neq h\circ g$.

Comment: if for G  f(x) =-x and g(x) = x-1  and  for H h is conjugate to x-1, then Are G and H isomorphic?

Comment: @hattabhawete I have no idea how to check this.

Comment: @hattabhawete if you add additional requirements on $f$ and $g$, you should edit your question

Comment: anyway if $f(x)=-x$, $g(x)=x-1$, and $h(x)$ is defined to be $x-1$ for $x\ge -1$ and $h(x)=-2x$ for $x\le -1$, then $h,g$ are conjugate, $\langle f,g\rangle$ is an infinite dihedral group but $\langle f,h\rangle$ is not.

Comment: h(x) =2x? to be continuous

Comment: But H is it solvable? where H is generated by -x and a homeomorphism h is conjugate to x-1.